# Fast build tools and make alternatives?

Tags: c, linux, build, gnu-make

I'm beginner C programmer and I have one not very big project in C.
I written simple perl script for building it with different options. And my project wasn't split into object files, I just included .c into each other and built all with one compiler call.

But my project was growing and compilation time reached 1s+ (I like script-style debuging with lot of change little bit && run steps), so I decided to split my project into object files, link them together and use gnu make to check if source have changed, as everyone does.

I expected that this will make building faster. BUT NO! make is so slow, it made compilation even slower several times and I even haven’t split my project completely (one .o per .c file) yet, just in about 5 object files (project has about 20 .c files) ! 
It even slower or about same time for make to check if files where changed than to rebuild entire project when .c files just included into each other!

So now I just using enhanced version of my perl script "build system". I split project into several big parts and rebuilding only one of them (other are 3rd party libs mostly) and it works very fast. Also it's more flexible and easy to manage for me than makefiles, because I have lot of build option including crosscompiling. But this is reinventing the bicycle.

Having all c files included into each other isn't best practice, yes?
What should I use?

I wanted to name this question "Why make is so slow?" but I know why - launching a shell for every code line is heavy task. Maybe for really big projects it works ok, but for me it has too much overhead.

So what are best practices and tools for managing C projects? What building tools are fast and flexible?
I don't want make-like crap forking on every move, making build slower than naive include-all-into-one-file even if using several cores

Comment: Make is not slow. You have probably not created a proper makefile, having it rebuild targets that it shouldn't need to.  A properly created makefile can compile in parallel too with the -j argument, further speeding things up. Show your makefile and the output you get. Also include some info about what "slow" means. Does it take minutes ? Tens of seconds ? How much compared to your perl script ?

Comment: Sounds like your computer is grossly underpowered for development. I have projects with hundreds of .c files that build in a second or two with traditional Makefiles. I'd especially look at your disk drives.

Comment: have you included too many uncessary headers in each source file?

Comment: It was several weeks ago, I already deleted it.
I know make should check if source changed and I written normal makefile. The problem is that when rebuilding entire project make is several times slower than naive include-all way.

Comment: And when rebuilding just part of the project it's took about same time

Comment: It's because my c files are just 200-500 lines and launching a sheel and compiler takes time comparable to compiling itself, so overhead is big. My project only takes 2-3sec to build in naive include-all-way

Comment: @user1940679 Still, there's literally hundres of thousands, if not more, projects that manage fine with plain makefiles. I'd say you didn't create an optimal makefile and possibly development envoronment - and you're not going to find tools that do it faster.

Comment: No, my pc isn't underpowered, I have samsung ssd, 16gb of ram and 3+Ghz i7
The problem is that project is too small so overhead of launching shell and compiler is big.

Comment: I'll try to take open source project - lua interpreter (because it's used in my project already), that uses makefile and make naive building when all c filed are just included in one. And compare building time. It'll prove that I'm right that make is slow for small project or wrong and just couldn't write good makefile.  I'll post result tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you try the combination of CMake with the ninja generator.

Ninja is a lot faster than make and CMake makes it easy to configure the project.

- http://www.cmake.org
- https://martine.github.io/ninja/